# "Error: An SP-initiated SAML response from *IdP* was received unexpectedly", what could cause this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, component-space

I have upgraded to the latest stable version of ComponentSpace.Saml2.Net (6.5.0). So I had to refactor the code changing the old syntax: "PartnerCertificateString=..., SecondaryPartnerCertificateString=..., etc... " to the newer syntax using the "List" to define the certificates used.

When logging in via SSO, I get this error. It was working fine before.

I've searched online for the error and I found this thread on ComponentSpace's forum: https://componentspace.com/forums/12428/ but none of the solutions there seem to work.

I'm using https and I've added the following rule to the Web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
     <outboundRules>
       <rule name="Set SAML session cookie flags">
         <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="SAML_SessionId=[^;\s]*" />
         <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None" />
       </rule>
     </outboundRules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I can see the SAML_sessionId cookie in the browser's storage

Comment: What I think is happening is the old cookie still exists and is being used.  The new code will not work with the old cookie.  You need to delete the old cookie and try again.  If that is not the case it is possible when you upgraded to new library not all the code got recompiled and you need to do a clean build which will remove all the intermediate obj files and force all the code to recompile.

Comment: I'm using an incognito window so cookies are not already set, I have tried clearing them anyway. I have done a clean rebuild and that doesn't fix the issue. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Read first answer in your link.  You are sending a "SAML authn request" to get a cookie and failing.  The solution in link was to change from HTTP to HTTPS.  Most likely in your case HTTPS is failing due to TLS failing.  Before a HTTPs Request is sent TLS protocol is used to establish a encrypted connection.  What OS are you using on both client and server?  The certificate has an encryption mode and both client and server OS has to support the encryption mode.  You also have to use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Certificate has to be loaded on both client and server.

Comment: I took a look into that, everything seems to be set up fine. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

I've been using MySql to store SSO Sessions and I had to add `UpdateDateTime` and `ExpirationDateTime` columns of type `DateTime NULL` to the `SSOSessions` table.

That was the only issue.

I found about the issue by enabling SAML trace and checking the logs. (https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/17/Enabing-SAML-Trace)